# Prevent clang-format from breaking after brace in constructor's initializer list

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have a class constructor definition that initializes a couple of strings.

Basically, I'd expect clang-tidy to give me this after formatting:

```
A::A()
    : index{1}, string_one{"some pretty string"},
      string_two{"another pretty string"} {
}
```

However, it gives me this:

```
A::A()
    : index{1}, string_one{"some pretty string"}, string_two{
                                                      "another pretty string"} {
}
```

I would like clang-format to try to avoid breaking between a parameter name (e.g., `string_two`) and its constructor arguments. Instead, I want it to move the parameter and its constructor arguments together to a new line.

Is there a way to make clang-format to give me the former output? If I use parenthesis instead of brackets to initialize the parameters, it will produce the output I expect.

These are the contents of my `.clang-format` file:

```
---
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
Language: Cpp
Standard: c++17

TabWidth: 4
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: -4
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
NamespaceIndentation: All
ColumnLimit: 80

BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None

...
```

Answer (score 0):

With clang-format-14 you can achieve your desired formatting if you add these to your .clang-format file:

```
PackConstructorInitializers: Never
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
    AfterFunction: true
```

Have in mind that setting the `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom` will most likely make additional modifications to your code since you are no longer inheriting that behavior from LLVM.

For more information consult the official documentation: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, what I wanted to achieve was clang-format keeping parameter names (i.e., `string_two{`) and its arguments (i.e., `"another pretty string"}`) in the same line, but still allow initializers to be packed. I have updated the example in the question so that is now clear.